# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.DLL'

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite

[image: Error]

Este es el error que me aparece en algunas computadoras cuando corro mi aplicación, tengo las librerías `SQLite.Interop.dll` y `System.Data.SQLite.dll` en el mismo directorio del ejecutable.

También probé copiando las dos librerías a `C:\windows\system32` y `C:\windows\SysWOW64`

Como referencias en el proyecto tengo `System.Data.SQLite`, quise agregar la otra para probar y me aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy teniendo el mismo problema que tú en algunos ordenadores de 64 bits a pesar de que la configuración de compilación de mi proyecto esta en 32 y que la PC con la que desarrollo es 64 y corre excelente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno la solución comienza con una explicación **obligada** y  una muestra de cuales pueden ser tus puntos de salida.

Por empezar explicarte que para utillizar SQLite es muy importante saber en que **arquitectura estamos compilando**. Ya que al compilar en **x86** SQLite.Interop.dll es uno y en **x64** es otro.

Teniendo en cuenta que en algunas maquinas como dices te funciona (al igual que a mi) me costó un poco más pero descubri por donde viene el problema.

El problema es que de seguro en esas máquinas no tienes instalado el **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)**

Bendito: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Yo tengo instalado los dos paquetes (el de x64 y el de x86) en mi máquina de desarrollo pero en la computadora que me sucedía el mismo problema que a vos solo descargué el Redistributable Package (x86) y deje de tener la misma ventana de error como la tuya.

En resumen:

Si compilo mi proyecto en **x86 (para 32 bits)** debo tener en cuenta:

1. Transportar en el mismo directorio raíz de la aplicación el **System.Data.SQLite** de **x86**.
2. Transportar en el mismo directorio raíz de la aplicación el **SQLite.Interop.dll** de **x86**.
3. Tener instalado el **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)**.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, cuando haga las pruebas aviso como fue, mientras tanto agrego otras preguntas. Que relación tiene Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86), lo que contiene son librerías de Microsoft y el error de librería es de SQLITE, lo que me llama la atención es que tanto mi maquina como en las otras que no funciona son 64 bits

Comment: No tengo precisamente la noción de que tendrá que ver, solo el hecho de que eso lo arregló, por otro lado no es muy loco pensar que si la librería de SQLite para .NET está escrita en C++ quizás necesite de esos paquetes para poder funcionar correctamente. Por otra parte no es que "haya descubierto" la rueda sino que de tanto buscar la respuesta la encontre en SO en Ingles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191283/missing-system-data-sqlite-dll-reported-after-installation/17195350#17195350

Comment: Ahi mismo si entras verás que planteaban la respuesta que yo probé y que te dí, por eso es que la he escrito :)

Comment: Por ultimo no olvides marcar como correcta la respuesta si te ha servido finalmente.

Answer (score 4):

A mi se me solucion instalando `System.Data.SQLite` desde el Nuget.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instalas el primero y se te instalan los otros 3.

Answer (score -1):

A mi me sirvió esto, ya que tenía el mismo problema luego de instalar System.Data.SQLite por Nuget:
[Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28092497)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**
Se debe instalar por Nuget `System.Data.SQLite` o `System.Data.SQLite.Core` para el caso de solo NET Framework, luego en el proyecto se debe crear dos carpetas llamadas x86 y x64, en cada una se debe agregar `SQLite.Interop.dll` dependiendo de la arquitectura, esta dll se encuentra en la carpeta `packages` que se creó al instalar el Nuget, por ejemplo:

```
..\MiProyecto\packages\Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework.1.0.113.0\build\net46
```

La carpeta `build`contiene varias sub carpetas para diferentes versiones del NET Framework.

Por último, en cada una de las dlls agregadas se debe cambiar en la ventana de propiedades la propiedad: **"Cambiar en el directorio de salida"** de **"No copiar"** a **"Copiar siempre"**.