# Sqlite ADO.NET C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

Trabajo con Sqlite, ADO.NET y C#
Veo que hay una dll que es el conector para arquitectura de 32 y 64 bits ¿que pasa si quiero compilar para 32 y 64 bits?
¿Cual es la mejor solución?

Instale Sqlite desde nuget
Tengo que tener instalado en todas las pc clientes The Visual C++ 2010 SP1 runtime for x86 is statically linked. The .NET Framework 4.0 is required. Al momento de hacer la instalación de la aplicación?

```
public void Create(Configuracion entity)
    {
        using (var cn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= XmlSri.db;Version=3;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "INSERT INTO Configuraciones(Ruc, RazonSocial, RutaXmlGenerado, RutaXmlAutorizado, RutaFirma, ClaveFirma, Ambiente)" +
                    " VALUE(@Ruc, @RazonSocial, @RutaXmlGenerado, @RutaXmlAutorizado, @RutaFirma, @ClaveFirma, @Ambiente)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ruc", entity.Ruc);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazonSocial", entity.RazonSocial);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RutaXmlGenerado", entity.RutaXmlGenerado);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RutaXmlAutorizado", entity.RutaXmlAutorizado);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RutaFirma", entity.RutaFirma);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClaveFirma", entity.Clave);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ambiente", entity.Ambiente);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Da error en la conexión
Utilice este manual [[HowTo] Use SqLite ADO.NET with C#](https://www.ivankristianto.com/howto-use-sqlite-ado-net-with-c/)

Le cambie la dirección de la ruta por una que apunta desde D... y nada da el mismo error.

Comment: Si tienes librerias concreta para cada arquitctura vas a tener que usar la que corresponde con la que definas para compilar, aunque en 64bits puedes usar la de 32, aunque quizas baje un poco la performance

Comment: @LeandroTuttini a que se debe este error: No se puede cargar el archivo DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

Comment: Tengo que tener instalado, ¿The Visual C++ 2010 SP1 runtime for x86 is statically linked. The .NET Framework 4.0 is required.? en todos los clientes que voy a instalar la app?

Comment: porque menciona Interop, esto hace referencia al uso de un componente COM, como referencias al componente de Sqlite que usa ado.net?

Comment: tienes que referenciarlo desde nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Comment: Al instalar por nuget queda automaticamente referenciado y al persistir me sale este error: No se puede cargar el archivo DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: estas compilando en 64 o 32 bits ? esto sucede cuando ejecutas desde el VS?

Comment: Plataforma de destino Any CPU debería cambiar a 86?, si cuando ejecuto VS para poder pesistir mi primer registro.

Comment: revisa este comentario https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23513/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll

Comment: Tengo instalado ambas versiones de Visual Studio C++ mejor regresare a Sql Compact, lo de usar un xml como base de datos me quita tiempo en revisar.

Comment: no veo que Interop ntenga que ver con los componente de c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede deberse a dos problemas:

1- Debas copiar o indicar que la dll de interop se ubique junto a exe que se genera

[No se puede cargar DLL ‘SQLite.Interop.dll’](http://blog.escuelactec.com/no-se-puede-cargar-dll-sqlite-interop-dll/)

Para esto deberias agregar la dll en la solucion indicando en las propiedad `Copiar en el directorio` y seleccionar `Copiar siempre`

2- Debas instalar [sqlite-netFx35-setup-bundle-x86-2008-1.0.81.0.exe](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.81.0/sqlite-netFx35-setup-bundle-x86-2008-1.0.81.0.exe)

Comment: por ese conector estaba apuntando.

Comment: intenta tambien definir que compile a 32bit (x86)  a ver si eso cambia el uso del interop

Comment: Si porque no encuentro SQLite.Interop.dll tan solo que lo busque en la web

Comment: podrias agregarla por nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Interop.dll/

Comment: Mejor, me dio este error El ensamblado de modo mixto se ha compilado con la versión 'v2.0.50727' del runtime y no se puede cargar en el runtime 4.0 sin información de configuración adicional.

Comment: Install-Package : No se pudo instalar el paquete 'SQLite.Interop.dll 1.0.103'. Está intentando instalar este paquete en un proyecto 
que tiene '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' como destino, pero el paquete no contiene referencias de ensamblado o archivos de contenido 
compatibles con dicho marco. Para obtener más información, póngase en contacto con el autor del paquete.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

Comment: Se soluciono instalando la versión sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.109.0.exe